# Remove target=“_blank” from Google sheet/doc

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to somehow remove the target=“_blank” from a published google sheet via script or something?

If so what would that script look like and how would I go about inputting it?

The reason I ask is I have many users accessing the Google sheet but they complain that each hyperlink in the sheet opens a new tab rather than the same window.

Comment: Are those `target="_blank"` added manually to each hyperlink or they are added by the "Publish to the web" built-in function?

Comment: Do you want the links to act as normal text string only?

Comment: They are auto added via Publish to the web" built-in function

Comment: I want the links to still work as hyperlinks, just not open them in a new window each time.